Gate-All-Around FET (GAAFET) nanosheet 3d illustration
I'm trying to create a 3D representation of a GAAFET (Gate-All-Around Field-Effect Transistor) nanosheet using TikZ in LaTeX. I have attempted a 2D schematic, but I would like to improve it and create a more accurate 3D model of the GAAFET structure.
\documentclass[14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage[lmargin=1.3in, rmargin=1in, tmargin=1in, bmargin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Draw the substrate
    \fill[gray!30] (-2,-1.5) rectangle (2,-2);
    \node at (0,-2.2) {Substrate};

    % Draw the source and drain
    \fill[blue!30] (-2,-1) rectangle (-1,1);
    \node at (-1.5,-1.2) {Source};

    \fill[blue!30] (1,-1) rectangle (2,1);
    \node at (1.5,-1.2) {Drain};

    % Draw the nanosheet (channel)
    \fill[green!50] (-1,0.2) rectangle (1,-0.2);
    \node at (0,-0.5) {Channel (Nanosheet)};

    % Draw the Gate-All-Around (GAA)
    \draw[thick, red] (-1,0.6) -- (1,0.6) -- (1,-0.6) -- (-1,-0.6) -- cycle;
    \node at (0,0.8) {Gate-All-Around (GAA)};

    % Add gate connections
    \draw[thick, red] (-1,0.6) -- (-2,0.6);
    \draw[thick, red] (1,0.6) -- (2,0.6);

    % Label the regions
    \node at (-1.5,0.7) {Gate};
    \node at (1.5,0.7) {Gate};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Thank you in advance
Here's the desired outcome:

If you had worked through the other thread (which is based on this thread), you would know that you can draw many cuboids of the kind

here with a few simple modifications to the pic in the linked code.
The relevant code then looks something like this:
% Base 1 
\pic{cuboid={18}{10}{2}{black}{black}{none}{b1}};
% Base 2
\path ([shift={(0,-3.5,0)}]b1-D2) pic{cuboid={18}{3.5}{5}{blue}{none}{blue}{b2}};
% Base 3
\path ([shift={(0,-3.5-3,0)}]b1-D2) pic{cuboid={18}{3}{5}{black}{none}{black}{b3}};
% Base 4
\path (b1-A2) pic{cuboid={18}{3.5}{5}{blue}{blue}{blue}{b3}};
% Gate without fill  (for coordinates)
\path[] ([shift={(-1.5,0,0)}]b3-Start) pic{cuboid={3}{10}{13}{none}{none}{none}{gwf}};

% Drain 1,2,3
\foreach[count=\No] \z in {2,5,8}{%%
\path[] ([shift={(3,5-1.5,\z)}]gwf-A1) pic{cuboid={7.5}{3}{1}{black}{brown}{green}{d\No}};
}%%

% Gate with fill
\path[] ([shift={(-1.5,0,0)}]b3-Start) pic{cuboid={3}{10}{13}{green}{green}{green}{g}};

% Source 1,2,3
\foreach[count=\No] \z in {2,5,8}{%%
\path[] ([shift={(-7.5,5-1.5,\z)}]gwf-A1) pic{cuboid={7.5}{3}{1}{black}{brown}{green}{s\No}};
}%%

But the loveless way in which you put in pseudo-MWEs which have nothing to do with what you're looking for, and don't even edit them properly; and how you don't even put a tick on older threads to signal that they're finished; shows that you don't care about the whole thing anyway.
Well, I like solving complicated TikZ problems; and I'm not here to parent anyone.
PS: I'm skipping the conical shape of the green component here.

\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds} 

\definecolor{myleftgray}{HTML}{63656C}
\definecolor{myrightgray}{HTML}{7B797D}
\definecolor{mytopgray}{HTML}{989CA0}
\definecolor{myleftgreen}{HTML}{B3C379}
\definecolor{myrightgreen}{HTML}{BBC77D}
\definecolor{mytopgreen}{HTML}{DBD9A2}
\definecolor{myleftblue}{HTML}{577DB7}
\definecolor{myrightblue}{HTML}{6F95CA}
\definecolor{mytopblue}{HTML}{88B1DC}
\definecolor{mybgcolor}{HTML}{ECEBEC}

\pgfmathsetmacro\wx{18}
\pgfmathsetmacro\wy{154}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\s{8.75mm}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
y={(\wy:\s)},x={(\wx:\s)}, z={(0cm,\s)},
font=\sffamily\Huge\bfseries,
background rectangle/.style={draw=none, fill=mybgcolor}, 
show background rectangle,
%% Cuboid ===========================
% \pic{cuboid={x}{y}{z}{leftcolor}{rightcolor}{topcolor}{name}};    
pics/cuboid/.style n args={7}{
code={%%
\coordinate[alias=#7-A1](A1) at (0,0);
\coordinate[alias=#7-B1](B1) at (#1,0);
\coordinate[alias=#7-C1](C1) at (#1,#2);
\coordinate[alias=#7-D1](D1) at (0,#2);
\coordinate[alias=#7-A2](A2) at (0,0,#3);
\coordinate[alias=#7-B2](B2) at (#1,0,#3);
\coordinate[alias=#7-C2](C2) at (#1,#2,#3);
\coordinate[alias=#7-D2](D2) at (0,#2,#3);
% Cuboid draw
\path[draw=none, fill=none] (A1) -- (B1) -- (C1)  -- (D1) -- cycle;
\path[draw=none, fill=#6,
local bounding box=#7-box,% Cuboid coordinates 1/5
] (A2) -- (B2) coordinate[pos=0.5, label=](#7-Start) % Cuboid coordinates 2/5
  -- (C2)  -- (D2) coordinate[pos=0.5, label=](#7-End)% Cuboid coordinates 3/5
    -- cycle;
\path[fill=#4, draw=none] (A1) -- (A2) -- (D2) -- (D1) --cycle;
\path[fill=#5, draw=none] (A1) -- (B1) -- (B2) -- (A2) --cycle;
%
\coordinate[label=](#7-start) at (0,0.5*#2,#3);% Cuboid coordinates 4/5
\coordinate[label=](#7-end) at (#1,0.5*#2,#3);% Cuboid coordinates 5/5
% ===================================
% ===================================
%% Show Coordinates and Name - comment out! =======
%\draw[dashdotted, red] (#7-start) -- (#7-end) node[midway, above]{#7};% Test
%\draw[dotted, red] (#7-Start) -- (#7-End) node[]{};% Test
%% ===================================
},%%
},% ==================
]
% Base 1 
\pic{cuboid={18}{10}{2}{black}{black}{none}{b1}};
% Base 2
\path ([shift={(0,-3.5,0)}]b1-D2) pic{cuboid={18}{3.5}{5}{myleftblue}{none}{mytopblue}{b2}};
% Base 3
\path ([shift={(0,-3.5-3,0)}]b1-D2) pic{cuboid={18}{3}{5}{black}{none}{black}{b3}};
 % Base 4
\path (b1-A2) pic{cuboid={18}{3.5}{5}{myleftblue}{myrightblue}{mytopblue}{b3}};
% Gate without fill  (for coordinates)
\path[] ([shift={(-1.5,0,0)}]b3-Start) pic{cuboid={3}{10}{13}{none}{none}{none}{gwf}};

% Drain 1,2,3
\foreach[count=\No] \z in {2,5,8}{%%
\path[] ([shift={(3,5-1.5,\z)}]gwf-A1) pic{cuboid={7.5}{3}{1}{none}{myrightgray}{mytopgray}{d\No}};
}%%

% Gate with fill
\path[] ([shift={(-1.5,0,0)}]b3-Start) pic{cuboid={3}{10}{13}{myleftgreen}{myrightgreen}{mytopgreen}{g}};

% Source 1,2,3
\foreach[count=\No] \z in {2,5,8}{%%
\path[] ([shift={(-7.5,5-1.5,\z)}]gwf-A1) pic{cuboid={7.5}{3}{1}{myleftgray}{myrightgray}{mytopgray}{s\No}};
}%%

% Annotations
\node[above=\s, scale=1.75] at (g-C2) {Gate-All-Around};
\draw[very thick] ([yshift=-\s]g-start) -- +(100:6) node[anchor=east]{Gate};
\draw[very thick] ([xshift=\s]s3-start) -- +(70:4) node[anchor=east]{Source};
\draw[very thick] ([xshift=-\s]d3-end) -- +(70:4) node[anchor=east]{Drain};

% CoSy
\begin{scope}[>=stealth, yshift=-0mm, cyan, very thick]
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node [below] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node [below] {$y$};
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node [pos=1.3] {$z$};
\end{scope}

%% Tests
%\node[] at (0,-3){s=\s};
%\draw (b3-Start) circle(3mm); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

